# Outlook 2003 does not import .ics calendar while outlook 2007 does

Tags: php, outlook-2003, icalendar

I have an .ics file I manually create with PHP like the following:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:Some description here
LOCATION:Scheduled PTO
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20101104
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20101103
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:PTO - 8.00 hour(s)
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
X-MICROSOFT-MSNCALENDAR-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This works fine when importing into outlook 2007 (as well as Google calendar).  In outlook 2003 I get the following error:

"This error can appear if you have attempted to save a recurring Lunar Calendar in iCalendar format.  To avoid this error, set the appointment option to Gregorian instead of Lunar."

Is there something I need to change in the .ics file to get this to work with Outlook 2003?

(I don't have Outlook 2003 to test with at the moment)

Comment: PHP can't generate .ics files. A library written in PHP however can, maybe you name it in your post?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use a library, I create the ics file manually.  Question updated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after some trial and error with a 2003 test system and I found that adding the following:

```
DTSTAMP:20101103T120000Z
```

allowed Outlook 2003 to import the .ics file without breaking 2007, iCal or Google.
I also, for good measure added the UID line to my final .ics file.

So, my final .ics file looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:Some description here
LOCATION:Scheduled PTO
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20101104
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20101103
DTSTAMP:20101103120000Z
UID: VACATIOND41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:PTO - 8.00 hour(s)
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
X-MICROSOFT-MSNCALENDAR-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

All I did was create a manual entry in outlook 2003, saved it as a .ics and did a comparison on what was missing/different from my original.

All works well now.

**UPDATE**
One additional change, I removed the `VERSION:2.0` bit and that made all work even more reliably.

Comment: Tried in 2003 and it does NOT work.  Comes up with a message saying some fields are invalid.  Works in 2010 though.  Are you meaning it works with 2010 and 2007?

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting "VERSION:2.0" was all it took to make a 3rd party .ics meeting open fine for me in Outlook 2003.

Answer (score 0):

It does indeed appear that 2003 has need of the following three fields: the `METHOD` field posted outside of the `VEVENT` section, and within the `VEVENT` section the `DTSTAMP` and `UID` fields. `DTSTAMP` must be a valid timestamp so you can just copy the value found under `DTSTART`, and UID can be an arbitrary string it appears.

```
METHOD:PUBLISH
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:$COPY_VALUE_AT_DTSTART
UID:placeholder
```

I have also come across calendar events which include an `ATTENDEE#` field, eg `ATTENDEE#<Client 300000 "Jane Doe">`. I removed that line and got the file to import. All these malformed ics files failed with a message stating

> **Microsoft Office Outlook**
>
> Cannot import vCalendar file.
>
> Show Help >>